# How to append multiple checkbox values into textarea with a click of one checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

hi guys need your help again. I have a javascript function which pass checkbox values into a textarea 'recipients', it works fine on check/uncheck and pass values accordingly into a textarea. What i want is to have one checkbox to check all checkbox and append values into a textarea.

Below is my javascript to pass vales into textarea 'recipients':

```
var textbox = document.getElementsByName("recipients")[0];
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("email");
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    checkbox.onclick = (function(chk){
        return function() {
            var value = "";
            for (var j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++) {
                if (checkboxes[j].checked) {
                    if (value === "") {
                        value += checkboxes[j].value;
                    } else {
                        value += ", " + checkboxes[j].value;
                    }
                }
            }
            textbox.value = value;
        }
    })(checkbox);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: daniel, but my data need to be retrieve from db so i need to use php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) When you make a change to checkbox you need to check all checkboxes and update to textarea.

(2) function `updateAllChecked` will handle all the check and update.

(3) for check all, if it is checked, set all email checkboxes to checked and call `.change()` to trigger the change event.

```js
$("input[name=email]").change(function() {
  updateAllChecked();
});

$("input[name=addall]").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("input[name=email]").prop('checked', true).change();
  } else {
    $("input[name=email]").prop('checked', false).change();
  }
});

function updateAllChecked() {
  $('#recipients').text('');
  $("input[name=email]").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      let old_text = $('#recipients').text() ? $('#recipients').text() + ', ' : '';
      $('#recipients').text(old_text + $(this).val());
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="email_1">email_1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="email_2">email_2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="email_3">email_3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="email_4">email_4<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="addall">Add All Email<br>

<textarea id="recipients"></textarea>
```

Comment: hi, your code works fine for static html but am retrieving recipients email from db: <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_applied_job->email;?>" name="email" id="email">

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using an array with a final `join()` once your array is populated. I think it's a lot cleaner:

```
    checkbox.onclick = (function(chk){
        return function() {
            var valueArray = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++) {
                if (checkboxes[j].checked) {
                    valueArray.push(checkboxes[j].value); //add value to array
                }
            }
            textbox.value = valueArray.join(", "); //join with comma separators
        }
    })(checkbox);
```

You could also extract the function and invoke the extracted function rather than adding the content of the function to every checkbox, but w/out seeing your HTML, it's a little hard to discern exactly what you're doing and why you're looping the way you are.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys here is my html and php, I retrieve recipients email from db:

```
here is my html with php, I retrieve recipients email from db.:           <?php 
      $i='';
      if($result_applied_jobs): ?>
         <div class="tg-wrap">
             <table id="tg-s6tTH" class="tg" style="width: 100%;">
                <tr><th style="width: 12%"><label><input type="checkbox" name="addall" id="addall"/>&nbsp;Select all</label></th><th style="width: 7%">Sl. No.</th><th style="width: 20%">Applicant's Name</th><th style="width: 25%">Job Title</th><th style="width: 13%">Apply Date</th><th>Cover Letter</th></tr><?php
            foreach($result_applied_jobs as $row_applied_job):
        $i++;
        ?> 
       <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_applied_job->email;?>" name="email" id="email"></td>
            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('candidate/'.$this->custom_encryption->encrypt_data($row_applied_job->job_seeker_ID));?>"><?php echo $row_applied_job->first_name.' '.$row_applied_job->last_name;?></a></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('jobs/'.$row_applied_job->job_slug);?>"><?php echo $row_applied_job->job_title;?></a></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5f6f81"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo date_formats($row_applied_job->applied_date, 'M d, Y');?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_applied_job->c_letter;?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php     endforeach; ?>
            </table>
            </div><?php
            else:?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;No application received</div>
      <?php endif;?>
```

here is another portion for textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="recipientss" readonly="" placeholder="check the checkbox against applicants you want to send a message"><?php echo set_value('recipients');?></textarea>
```